# is my factor() and lm(), summary() output interpretation correct in R?

Tags: r

I want to know if I am interpreting the factor() function in r correctly. Suppose I have a variable with 10 levels let's say these are the different exposures of a study plan. I make it a factor using either `factor()` or `as.factor()`. When seeing the summary of my `lm()` (making up an example):

I know by default `factor1` is treated as a reference in r so it is not usually output.

`intercept: 10`
`factor2 = 30`
`factor3 = 10`
`factor4 = 57`
`factor5 = 4`
`factor6 = 34`
`factor7 = 56`
`factor8 = 89`
`factor9 = 78`
`factor10 = 8`

if a person was exposed to factor4 would this mean that their test score is intercept + factor4 which is 67?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about interpreting results from statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Yes, their *modeled* (predicted) test score would be 67 (if there are no covariates). You can check using the `predict` function.

Comment: `model.matrix(lm(...))` will show the model matrix that it generates, at least conceptually, as an intermediate step  and from that you can understand model.

Comment: @MrFlick did not know that, sorry and thanks